# Performance Optimize Marker Animation

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have an Openlayers application, which has a marker pulsating on the current location of the user.

The animation of the marker looks good, but is extremly performance heavy on my machine, is there any way I can optimize the performance on this function?

```
function pulsate(feature, style, duration) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();

  var key = map.on('postcompose', function(event) {
    var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
    var frameState = event.frameState;
    var flashGeom = feature.getGeometry().clone();
    var elapsed = frameState.time - start;
    var elapsedRatio = elapsed / duration;
    var radius = ol.easing.easeOut(elapsedRatio) * 35 + 5;
    var opacity = ol.easing.easeOut(1 - elapsedRatio);
    var fillOpacity = ol.easing.easeOut(0.5 - elapsedRatio)

    vectorContext.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: radius,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, " + fillOpacity + ")"
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, " + fillOpacity + ")",
          width: 3 + opacity
        })
      })
    }));

    vectorContext.drawGeometry(flashGeom);
    vectorContext.setStyle(style);
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(feature.getGeometry());

    if (elapsed > duration) {
      ol.Observable.unByKey(key);
      pulsate(feature, style, duration); // recursive function
    }

    map.render();
  });
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle for playing around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/4arb5ka1/1/

Comment: Here my CPU is quite acceptable with Chrome.

Comment: Weird, my laptop fan starts spinning and all and my Visual Studio Code IDE is slowing down a lot until I remove the marker animation.

Comment: A little bit heavier than [this D3 pulsating](http://bl.ocks.org/chiester/11267307).

Comment: Any suggestions on just some small improvements to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Do not always render the map, but instead set an interval timer that changes the style of the feature depending on the elapsed time. This way you will not render the map all the time when nothing really changed.

```js
const feature = ... // get the event you want to animate from OL
const renderInterval = 100 // ms

setInterval(pulsate, renderInterval)

function pulsate() {
    var style = ... // set your style as needed, depending on elapsed time
    feature.setStyle(style)
    map.render()
}
```